# Is there any way to view/edit the zip archive comment field

Tags: archive-mode

Zip files have a comment field for files and an archive comment, that you can set activating the *--archive-comment* option and display them with the *zipnote* command.

Is there any emacs package to edit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a direct answer to your question whether there is some emacs package out there for setting the archive content but I have a solution for your problem:

Getting and setting the archive comment is relatively simple since that comment is the last thing in the archive.

After installing the following code in your initialization files (e.g. `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) you can display and change the archive comment of zip archives from within `archive-mode`.

Just open some zip-archive with emacs and type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `archive-zip-comment` <kbd>RET</kbd>. The current comment is shown in the minibuffer where you can edit its value and set it with <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Note, that you must save the zip file before the new comment takes effect on disk.

`archive-zip-comment` provides an input history. So, if you want to undo your changes you just go back in history (<kbd>↑</kbd>).

```el
(defun archive-zip-assert (&optional fun)
  "Assert that current buffer is an archive of subtype 'zip.
The error message "
  (assert (eq archive-subtype 'zip) nil "Function %s only works for archives of subtype zip" (or fun this-command)))

(defun archive-zip-eocd ()
  "Move point to the beginning of the end record of the central directory (eocd)."
  (archive-zip-assert)
  (goto-char (buffer-size))
  (assert (search-backward "PK\005\006" nil t)
      nil  "End of central directory signature not found in zip archive"))

(defun archive-zip-comment-start ()
  "Goto start of archive comment."
  (archive-zip-eocd)
  (forward-char 20);; offset comment length
  )

(defun archive-zip-comment-length ()
  "Get length of zip archive comment.
Warn if the end of the comment does not match the file end.
Goto start of string."
  (let* ((comment-length (archive-l-e (point) 2))
     (comment-end (progn (forward-char 2) (+ (point) comment-length -1))))
    (if (> comment-end (buffer-size))
    (warn "Zip file %s ends prematurely." (buffer-file-name))
      (when (< comment-end (buffer-size))
    (warn "Extra butes at end of zip file %s." (buffer-file-name))))
    comment-length))

(defun archive-zip-get-comment ()
  "Return zip archive comment of current zip archive buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (archive-zip-comment-start)
      (let* ((comment-length (archive-zip-comment-length)))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (+ (point) comment-length))))))

(defun archive-zip-set-comment (str)
  "Replace current zip archive comment with STR."
  (require 'bindat)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (archive-zip-comment-start)
      (let* ((inhibit-read-only t)
         (spec '((length u16r) (data str (length))))
         (data (bindat-pack spec (list (cons 'length (length str))
                       (cons 'data str))))
         (old-length (archive-zip-comment-length)))
    (delete-region (- (point) 2) (min (1+ (buffer-size)) (+ (point) old-length)))
    (insert data)))))

(defvar-local archive-zip-comment-history '()
  "Input history for zip archive comments.")
(defvar archive-zip-global-comment-history nil
  "Global variable for `archive-zip-comment-history'.")

(defun archive-zip-comment (str)
  "Display zip editable archive comment in minibuffer."
  (interactive (let ((current-comment (archive-zip-get-comment)))
         (add-to-history 'archive-zip-comment-history current-comment)
         (setq archive-zip-global-comment-history archive-zip-comment-history)
         (list (read-string
            "Archive comment: "
            current-comment
            '(archive-zip-global-comment-history . 1)))))
  (archive-zip-set-comment str))
```